When is money first mentioned in Holy Scriptures?
When is money first mentioned in Holy Scriptures? And what is the Hebrew word for it?
cf. my previous question: "Is money a consequence of Original Sin?"

The Bible isn't entirely in chronological order (in setting or in date written). Because of this "first mentioned" should probably be clarified.

It seems to be first mentioned in:

Gen. 23:9That he may give me the double cave, which he hath in the end of his field: for as much money [בְּכֶ֨סֶף, lit. "silver"] as it is worth he shall give it me before you, for a possession of a burying placeut det mihi speluncam duplicem, quam habet in extrema parte agri sui : pecunia digna tradat eam mihi coram vobis in possessionem sepulchri.


The word for money is pronounced "ke'sef" in Hebrew (both Biblical and modern).

I agree that the answer of @Geremia, by referring to Genesis, gives the most ancient event in which the Bible speaks of money. However, there is a tradition that the Book of Job may have been composed before Genesis. Moses (and possibly Joshua) are credited with setting the story down in Hebrew.
Based on the names and places found in the Book of Job, he likely lived between the times of Jacob and Moses.
If Job was written first, then the earliest suggestion of money according to when the story was written would be in verse 3:15:

11 “Why did I not die at birth,
        come out from the womb and expire?
12 Why did the knees receive me?
        Or why the breasts, that I should nurse?
13 For then I would have lain down and been quiet;
        I would have slept; then I would have been at rest,
14 with kings and counselors of the earth
        who rebuilt ruins for themselves,
15 or with princes who had gold,
        who filled their houses with silver.

